# Saveas dialog not recognizing wdFormatDocumentDefault as dotx, shows as PDF

Tags: vba, dialog

I've been trying to this code:

```
Dim dlgSaveAs As Dialog
Set dlgSaveAs = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)

With dlgSaveAs

    ' This according to every site I've looked at should set the Save As Type to .docx

    .Format = wdFormatDocumentDefault   
    .Display

End With
```

but when the dialog is displayed the "Save as Type" shows as PDF.

The code is in the MyDocuments module of a template document (.dotm).

Background: The template is a letter with Bookmarks that are replaced with text from a Form which then fills in the bookmarks from fields in the form.  I'm trying to then save the updated letter as a .docx file.

[I'm not looking for suggestions related to usage of Forms or Bookmarks - I've included to provide context in case the issue has something to do with Templates/Forms/Bookmarks, which I very much doubt.]

[Template Project Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ddpY.png)

[Save As Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qidS.png)

Comment: Press F2 for Object Browser in VBA editor and check that constant is available. Try using the value of that constant which is 16.

Comment: Also check the default save as option in Tools - Options (Alt + T, O) then Save tab.

Comment: Just so you know, when you encounter things like this, you can google ENUM and the enumeration that you want to know the value of and create your own if you dont want to add a reference to that library, which is helpful if you are using late binding. And if you aren't using `Option Explicit` it will treat all unknown ENUMS as the value `0`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

.Format = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument

By typing wdSaveFormat + period , you can see the enumeration of formats.

Comment: I'm familiar with the choices, I don't need an XML document, I need Word document.   According to the site  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdsaveformat-enumeration-word shows  that ennumeration  wdFormatDocumentDefault  gives a "Word default document file format. For Word, this is the DOCX format."

Comment: Changing  .format = wdFormatXMLDocument  to 
WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument did the trick, thanks.

Comment: I'm reliefed to hear that.